# Voice chat application using Smack API

Tags: java, smack

I'm currently developing an IM application in java using the Smack API. I've had no issues coding the simple functionalities such as instant messaging, group chat, and file sharing since there are plenty of online resources regarding the Smack API. I'm running this through an OpenFire server and connecting to a Spark client for testing purposes. All done locally so far.
My problem is to do with Jingle, or just getting voice chat established somehow. Are there any resources to help get me started with a Jingle voice chat application, or would it be easier to implement this functionality in an alternatives API? I'm not the best coder in the world and I need a jump start to figure the jingle API out.

Comment: Have you tried the developer's chatroom discussing XMPP itself? You can find it on https://xmpp.org/community/chat.html