# Java API like smack using XMPP to retrieve online GTalk-chat friends can receive audio or video call

Tags: java, audio, smack, google-talk, freeswitch

I am working on a module which is using inbuilt Freeswitch utility to call An Online GtalkUser.

I am in search of quick API interface to verify whether user's browser is enabled for Voice or Video Call( Browser requires gtalk-audio/video plugin, if I am not wrong).

This is VAS APP-- Where user first register using gtalk-id and password, then user call a common-IVR no. linked with E1 lines.

Flow- 
Incoming call detected

1. User Information is retrieved and sent Freeswitch for login (LT Time-user have to wait)
2. Simultaneously list of friends are retrieved by Google-data API
3. These list of contacts(Friend and their ID) verified using freeswitch inbuilt XMPP support.
4. If user is online, freeswitch's RTP protocol inbuilt support is used call the user.
5. If call is successful caller get ring buzzer of Gtalk-audio call
6. If call is failed user get respective failure IVR response

I want to use an API which can eliminate  setp 3/4/5(to some extent) to one point. SMACK-XMPP API is only able to detect user presence but not user browser's plugin-status.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Voice chat application using Smack API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14342666/voice-chat-application-using-smack-api)

Comment: Thanks but I have checked these lib/s I needs very exact answer without using streams. Just like Data/Info about user presence and its call receive capability.